# Android - How to access the File from a ParcelFileDescriptor?

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

According to the [FileProvider documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#openFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) the `fileProvider.openFile()` method returns

> a new [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html) with which you can access the file.

I have looked in [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html), but I cannot see how to access the File. So how do I access the File from a ParcelFileDescriptor?

Comment: use `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream`, what do you need `File` for?

Comment: Thanks. My app takes a photo and saves the Uri of the image which is stored in the database. I then need to get the File for that Uri so I can post the image to the server. Can you give me an example of how to use `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream`?

Comment: just like any other `InputStream`, what kind of problems do you have with `PFD.ACIS`?

Comment: but honestly if you have `Uri` then simply use `ContentResolver#openInputStream`, not `FileProvider#openFile`

Comment: Yes, I've now gone with the `ContentResolver#openInputStream` approach (as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028166/1617737). The FileProvider documentation is really lacking with this issue - many thanks for your help. If you'd like to provide it as a proper answer, please do and I will accept it.

Comment: sure, no problem